# import djcelery getting error

Tags: python, django, djcelery

When importing `djcelery` i am getting the below error. Is there any other method to install?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/home/c0mrade/Documents/wipi/wishpicker/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    import djcelery
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from celery import current_app as celery  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/five.py", line 307, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/_state.py", line 20, in <module>
    from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 351, in <module>
    from .functional import chunks, noop                    # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 18, in <module>
    from kombu.utils.functional import lazy, maybe_evaluate, is_list, maybe_list
ImportError: cannot import name lazy
```

Comment: Any other method than what? How have you tried to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo pip install -U django-celery
```

if you use ubuntu variants. This upgrades all your packages django-celery is dependent on